# CakePHP response stop deprecated

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 3.5 and two of the methods I want to use are deprecated and I can't find an alternative.

The methods are:

```
$this->response->send();
$this->response->stop();
```

I want to redirect to a different page and stop the execution of the current method. I've tried calling `die()` after my redirect and it doesn't work.

According to the [migration guide](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-4-migration-guide.html) the methods have been made obsolete.

Any thoughts?

Edit:

I'm trying to redirect users without access to certain pages. This is in the `initialize()` method in the controllers.

```
if ($allowedAccess) {
    $this->Flash->error("Insufficient rights to access that location");
    $this->redirect($this->referer());
    // FIXME - find alternative to deprecated methods
    return $this->response;
    $this->response->send();
    $this->response->stop();
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the Auth system that comes with Cake? It will do the redirect and flash automatically for you. Read this page: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html Oh, and next time, add the whole code in question when asking. Because this is now a different situation...

Comment: Because it's using LDAP and ensure users are in the proper group.

Comment: LDAP can work with the auth system of cake. There are at least two plugins for 3.x available and the new authentication layer I've worked on for CakePHP 3.5+ features LDAP support out of the box: https://github.com/cakephp/authentication/blob/master/docs/Identifiers.md#ldap If you favour your own implementation you should implement it as an adapter for the auth system.

Comment: I've been using [this plugin](https://github.com/QueenCityCodeFactory/LDAP) which is working great. But I need to be able to have certain pages accessible by certain groups and others not. It's more of a "you've logged in, you can view anything" plugin unless I've missed something in the docs.

Comment: What I've been adding is the ability to specify a list of groups that a user must be a part of in order to continue, which is working well, but when they aren't in those groups and they attempt to view a page, I need to redirect them which is what's not working. I can check the groups, I can verify they are a part of the groups, but the only way I've been able to redirect is with the deprecated method.

Comment: You can extend the plugin to do that for you or simply use this callback. https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#using-controllerauthorize it gets your user data.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying this in a controller? Simply return the response object from your controllers method:

```
public function index() {
    // Some code
    return $this->response;
}
```

send() was just a wrapper around phps [exit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php). Use exit() if you need to somewhere.

What happens when you return the response is that the [ActionDispatcher](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Http.ActionDispatcher) processes the return value and if it's a Response object. See the [__invoke()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/source-class-Cake.Http.ActionDispatcher.html#103-137) method.

The response will go through [the middleware layer](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html) and will be finally send by the [ResponseEmitter](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Http.ResponseEmitter.html) which is used by the [Server](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Http.Server.html). Check your webroot/index.php to see it:

```
// Bind your application to the server.
$server = new Server(new Application(dirname(__DIR__) . '/config'));
// Run the request/response through the application
// and emit the response.
$server->emit($server->run());
```

Comment: This suggestion isn't working for me. I added more details in my original post.